# TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array "email"

Tags: array, base-de-datos, mongodb, moongose

Quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de realizar este tipo de configuración trabajando con el modelode moongose o como seria la mejor forma según su experiencia de hacerlo.

Necesito guardar un array de contactos que vienen de otro modelos de schema, los mismos haran referencia al Schema de contactos y se agregaran en el Schema grupos, lo que en si deseo es poder guardar en un grupo varios contactos que estarán registrado en los Schema Contactos y a su vez de cada uno de los usuarios.

Models User-Contact

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
      user :{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
      email: [{ type:String, trim:true}]
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});

var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
      name: { type:String,  trim:true, require:true},
      lastname: { type:String,  trim:true,  require:true},
      email: { type:String, unique:true, trim:true, require:true},
      password: { type:String, trim:true, required: [true,'El Password debe ser mas de 6 caracteres']},
      nPhone: { type:String, trim:true, required: [true,'El Numero debe insertar el umero de telefono']},
      photoProfile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
      contacts:[ContactSchema] 
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});


//metodo para Eliminar password
UserSchema.methods.toJSON=function () {
      var obj =this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      
      return obj;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Models Grupo y Mensajes.

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
const  ContactSchema = require('../models/user');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var MessageSchema =  new Schema({

    messageContent:{ type:String },
    //idStatusMessage:{ type:Boolean },
    user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    urlFile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
},{     versionKey:false,
        timestamps:true, 

});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message' ,MessageSchema);


var GroupsSchema =  new Schema({
    nameChat:{ type:String },
    user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}, 
    email:[ContactSchema],
    //email :[{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Contact'}], 
    messageContent:{ type:String },
    messages:[MessageSchema] 
},{     versionKey:false,
        timestamps:true,      
});



//cargar grupos
GroupsSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Group',  GroupsSchema);
```

El error esta en esta linea

```
email:[ContactSchema],
//email :[{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Contact'}],
```

El tipo de Error.

```
     throw new TypeError('Invalid schema configuration: ' +
        ^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array `email`.See http://bit.ly/mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.
```

Los Grupos deben tener varios contactos o email en su defectos que seran los demas usuarios del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Opte por meter todos los schemas dentro de uno mismo de la siguiente forma,

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



var ContactSchema = new Schema({
      user :{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
      email: { type:String, trim:true}
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});

var Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

  
var UserSchema = new Schema({
      name: { type:String,  trim:true, require:true},
      lastname: { type:String,  trim:true,  require:true},
      email: { type:String, unique:true, trim:true, require:true},
      password: { type:String, trim:true, required: [true,'El Password debe ser mas de 6 caracteres']},
      nPhone: { type:String, trim:true, required: [true,'El Numero debe insertar el umero de telefono']},
      photoProfile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
      contact:[ContactSchema] 
      },{   versionKey:false,
            timestamps:true,      
});
var User= mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var MessageSchema =  new Schema({

      messageContent:{ type:String },
      //idStatusMessage:{ type:Boolean },
      user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
      urlFile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
  },{   versionKey:false,
          timestamps:true, 
  
  });

  var Message  = mongoose.model  ('Message' ,MessageSchema);

  var GroupsSchema =  new Schema({
      nameChat:{ type:String },
      user :{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}, 
      contact:[ContactSchema],
      //email :[{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Contact'}], 
      messageContent:{ type:String },
      //messages:[MessageSchema] 
  },{   versionKey:false,
          timestamps:true,      
  });


//metodo para Eliminar password
UserSchema.methods.toJSON=function () {
      var obj =this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      
      return obj;
};

//cargar grupos
GroupsSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group',  GroupsSchema);
```

Controlador del grupo

```
  saveGroup : function (req, res) {

        //recoger parametros por post
        var params= req.body;

        //validar datos
        try{
            var validate_nameChat = !validator.isEmpty(params.nameChat);
            var validate_contact = !validator.isEmpty(params.contact);          
        }catch(err){
                return  res.status(404).send({
                    message:'faltan datos por enviar // Save', 
            });
        }
        
        if(validate_nameChat && validate_contact){

        //crear objeto a guardar 
            var group = new Group();
        //asignar valores
            group.nameChat = params.nameChat;
            group.user = req.user.sub;
            group.contact = params.contact;
            //group.urlFile=null;

        //guardar topic
            group.save((err, groupStored) =>{
        //devolver una respuesta 
        console.log(err);
        console.log(groupStored);
                if (err || !groupStored) {
                    return  res.status(404).send({
                        status:'error',
                        message:'Grupo no se ha podido guardar, Valide el codigo'
                    });
                }
                return res.status(200).send({
                    status:'succes',
                    groupStored
                });

            });
      
        }else{
            return res.status(404).send({
                message:'Los datos no son Validos'
            });
        }
    },
```

pero ahora al poder realizar el guardado del grupo, pasandole un contacto que existe dentro de la BD me aparece este error.

```
POST /api/POST_GROUP/ 404 20.616 ms - 45
Error: Group validation failed: contact: Cast to embedded failed for value "'jl@gmail.com'" at path "contact"
    at ValidationError.inspect 

 contact: CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "'jl@gmail.com'" at path "contact"

   path: 'contact',
      reason: ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got jl@gmail.com
```